# What is allocator<T>

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a vector, and i have read that the best implementation uses the allocator class(memory header file). I have no idea what is it and the site cplusplus.com didn't help me at all.

Comment: [`std::allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator)

Comment: Related (not a duplicate, since it is a more-specific usage not covered by the present question): [What is a void `std::allocator`? ie: `std::allocator<void>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67053471/what-is-a-void-stdallocator-ie-stdallocatorvoid).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is an abstraction of memory management.

In C programming, you essentially use the functions `malloc()` and `free()` to allocate chunks of memory without needing to know how the chunks are allocated.  In C++, the functions are [`operator new()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/operator%20new/) and [`operator delete()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/operator%20delete/).

`std::allocator` is a template taking one type parameter, which is the type of objects to be allocated.  Instantiations of `std::allocator` use `operator new()` and `operator delete()` internally, but the fact that `std::allocator<T>` has information about what `T` is means that it knows how to construct and destroy `T` objects.

The four basic functions of `std::allocator<T>` are:

1. `allocate(size_type n)`

   Uses `operator new()` to allocate space for `n * sizeof (T)` bytes.  Note that none of the `n` `T` objects that are allocated are constructed;  unlike `new T()`, which both allocates space for one `T` object *and* calls a no-arg constructor, `allocate(size_type n)` only allocates space for `n` `T` objects. You need to use `construct()` to explicitly construct each one.
2. `deallocate(pointer p, size_type n)`

   Uses `operator delete()` to free the memory returned by a previous call to `allocate()`. Note that `deallocate()` only releases the space. You must explicitly call `destroy()` on each of the `n` `T` objects or else you may leak memory.
3. `construct(pointer p, const T& val)`

   Calls the `T` copy constructor for the `T` object located at `p`.
4. `destroy(pointer p)`

   Calls the `T` destructor on the `T` object located at `p`.

Comment: +1, Had read some articles and SO answers on `std::allocator` but this is first time I understood it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a class which does the memory management of the standard library container classes.
However, If you want to provide your own memory management you can do so, `std::allocator` provides the default memory management.

Comment: Yes, but how is it used in the vector implementation?

Comment: @RondogiannisAristophanes: Implementation dependent, as a user of the container, one need not know.